# fluidsynth - show active router rules

Tags: router, midi, fluid

In fluidsynth we can set up [routing MIDI signals](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/UserManual#midi-router). Say this way:

```
router_begin note
  router_chan 15   15  0    0  
router_end
```

If the rule is incorrect it does not work or is not accepted. I want to have an overview of currently working router rules.

I cannot find a command for fluidsynth, how to show/print out active router rules. Say something like:

```
router_show # it does not work
```

Do you have some idea how to display active routing rules in fluidsynth, which are currently applied on MIDI signals?

Is there any command that does show midi router rules in fluidsynth?

Comment: Thank you, Sirs, for your help. There is no such way... :-(